# Can I get file from Azure Storage with rest response?

Tags: android, rest, https, azure-storage

I have an Android 2.1 application. 
I need that that application download file from my storage in my Azure acount.
I can't use the APIs that Azure provide, Because my Android version is to old.
So, I tried to download that file by Rest service call.
I don't know why didn't I succeed to do that

That what I tried to do:

```
private String _url = "https://fake_azure_acount_name.blob.core.windows.net/";
private final String _thisClassName = "StorageProvider";
private final String _azurAcountName = "fake_azure_acount_name";

public String GetImage(String imagePath)
{
    String image = ExecuteGetRequest(imagePath, "Could not succeed get the requested image");
    return image;
}

private String ExecuteGetRequest(String getRequest, String errorMassageIfFailes)
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(_url + getRequest));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
        JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(tokener);
        return json;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(_thisClassName, errorMassageIfFailes, ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally 
    {
        try
        {
          httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(_thisClassName, "Failed to close http connection", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working directly with the REST API, I would strongly recommend reading the corresponding API documentation: [Get Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx). It does not look like you are doing Shared Key authentication, so you have two options:

1. Your container needs to allow anonymous access.
2. You need to use a Shared Access Signature.

Please see [Authentication for the Azure Storage Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx) and [Delegating Access with a Shared Access Signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee395415.aspx) for more information on authentication.

Comment: Serdar, Thanks alot for your answer. I tried to over the blogs. I don't know why, But I complicated with that. Do you have an example for build that request in Java? Thanks again